# is there Dictionary app on iphone that can translate word printed on real paper?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

Is there any Dictionary app act like this:
1.capturing the image of the word on the book by its camera
2.converting the image of the word to text,and show its meaning in other languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, application is called [Word Lens](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/word-lens/id383463868?mt=8), and the technology behind it is darn impressive :)
Have a look at the [video presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2OfQdYrHRs&feature=player_embedded).
But it only works for translations from english to spanish (and vice-versa). Supposedly more languages to come but no progress since it launched.